# AttributeError: on Tensor object

Tags: python, tf.keras

The code below returns an `AttributeError`

```
def save_best_model(path_folder, file_name, metric):

    if metric == 'f1':
        mode = 'max'
        
    elif metric == 'val_loss':
        mode = 'min'
        
    return ModelCheckpoint(path_folder + file_name + '.h5',
                           monitor=metric,
                           mode=mode,
                           verbose=1,
                           save_best_only=True)


History = model.fit(X_TRAIN, 
          Y_TRAIN,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
          epochs=EPOCHS, 
          validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
          callbacks=[F1Metrics(ner_aux.idx2tag),
                     save_best_model('','best_model',metric='f1')])
```

Yields

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Comment: Hi Govind, please add some more relevant code so we can reproduce this error. This code is incomplete

Comment: History = model.fit(X_TRAIN, 
          Y_TRAIN,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
          epochs=EPOCHS, 
          validation_split=VALIDATION_SPLIT,
          callbacks=[F1Metrics(ner_aux.idx2tag),
                     save_best_model('','best_model',metric='f1')])

Comment: this is the function which i am calling then i am getting  'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Comment: Thanks Govind, but we still need some more supporting information, what imports are you making, what is `model` and `ModelCheckpoint`. I cannot tell what the rest of the program is doing. Please have a look at [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And you should also include the entire traceback as well, not just the error message